# Automatic unmount when power taken - OS X MacBook Pro

Tags: macos

Is there any way to have my encrypted disk mounts automatically unmounted if power is taken from my MacBook Pro

While not completely safe, I am thinking it will help protect work data incase the laptop is stolen.

Comment: Are you saying you want to lose your mounts every time the charger is disconnected?

Comment: Correct - just like my Windows desktop computer looses truecrypt mounts when power is taken.